# Why am I getting a 'Assignment to property of function parameter ..' eslinterror?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier

In my reactcomponent I have a prop(array) called events. However I want to reassign values  like this:

```
 events.map(event => {
          event.createdDateTimeConverted = dateFunctions.formatDate(
            event.createdDateTime,
            'hh:mm A, DD MMM YYYY'
          );

          event.assignedDateTime = dateFunctions.formatDate(
            event.assignedDateTime,
            'hh:mm A, DD MMM YYYY'
          );

          event.dueDateTime = dateFunctions.formatDate(
            event.dueDateTime,
            'hh:mm A, DD MMM YYYY'
          );
 }
```

The code runs fine that is not the problem but I have to refactor because of an eslint/prettier error:

```
Assignment to property of function parameter 'event'
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `/* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */` at the top of the file.

OR use

```
events.map(ev => {

      let event = ev;

      event.createdDateTimeConverted = dateFunctions.formatDate(
        event.createdDateTime,
        'hh:mm A, DD MMM YYYY'
      );

      event.assignedDateTime = dateFunctions.formatDate(
        event.assignedDateTime,
        'hh:mm A, DD MMM YYYY'
      );

      event.dueDateTime = dateFunctions.formatDate(
        event.dueDateTime,
        'hh:mm A, DD MMM YYYY'
      );

}
```

For more info about this error. you can go to this [source](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign)

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the `event` as soon as brought in.

Try this:

```
events.map(e => {

      var event = e;

      event.createdDateTimeConverted = dateFunctions.formatDate(
        event.createdDateTime,
        'hh:mm A, DD MMM YYYY'
      );

      event.assignedDateTime = dateFunctions.formatDate(
        event.assignedDateTime,
        'hh:mm A, DD MMM YYYY'
      );

      event.dueDateTime = dateFunctions.formatDate(
        event.dueDateTime,
        'hh:mm A, DD MMM YYYY'
      );

}
```

Hope that helps